# Disabling indexing domain by Google

Tags: dns, indexing

I have two domains that are active and go to the same page.

One of them I want to exclude from indexing by Google.

Is this possible? How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you asked Google the same question?

Comment: Yes, I asked and found only answers about google robots file.determine in it file path and not the domain

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

Use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to tell Google which is the primary domain to be shown in their search results.